# When outputting to a file, how can I encode a struct as JSON?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Here's what I'm doing:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/my/path'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT name, info
FROM users
```

`info` is a nested struct (something similar to `struct<struct<string, string>, int>`). In the output text file, I want to encode it as JSON. Also, I can not use third party UDFs.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
insert overwrite local directory '/my/path' 
   row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.DelimitedJSONSerDe'  
   select name, info from users ;
```

DelimitedJSONSerDe is a hive built-in so no need for external libraries.